# Consequences of the Innovators in the hereafter?

Tags: practical-islam, sharia, punishment, bidah

My grandfather had lead his whole life by practicing ***incorrect islamic laws and especially   innovation.*** Recently he has afflicted with various old age diseases and waiting for death.
My question is, If he passes away whilst doing innovation what consequences will he be going to face in the hereafter? Please give me an appropriate answer regarding THIS situation.

Answer (score 0):

### Firstly, only Allah knows if a person will be punished for the actions of a person or if Allah wants to forgive the individual or take him to account then it's all upto Allah. However, the Prophet صلي الله عليه وسلم has told
عائشة رضي الله عنها قالت: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: (من أحدث في أمرنا هذا ما ليس منه فهو رد) رواه البخاري ومسلم، وفي رواية لـ مسلم (من عمل عملاً ليس عليه أمرنا فهو رد).

ص10 - كتاب شرح الأربعين النووية العباد - فوائد حديث من أحدث في أمرنا هذا - المكتبة الشاملة الحديثة

That who ever creates something that is not from the Deen then it is refuted.

However there are different types of level in innovation ( bid'ah Hasannah, bid'ah sayyiah... and so forth) so It depends on the type of innovation your grandfather was involved in.

والله اعلم بالصواب